# Having trouble calling a webservice method from apex test class

Tags: apex, class, unit-test

I have an apex class, which is the first block of code below.

I'm trying to have a test class create the lead, and use the leadrotator class, but I keep getting the "Save error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: leadrotator.rotateLead(SOBJECT:Lead)"

Any thoughts?

```
global class leadRotator{

    //General Process
    //1--Person pushes Lead Rotator Button
    //2--Needed from Lead: Territory, lead object/ID
    //3--Query all Lead Rotator Users in the territory of the lead taking Outside rep flag into consideration 
    //4--Pull in the user/id and lead rotator user id of the rep with the lowest leads rotated to them since the last time it was cleared
    //5--Create entry into Rotated Leads table using current user for "rotated by", user from comment 4 for "rotated to",
    //6--using lead from comment 2 for the lead reference, rotated date = today()
    //7--Increment the Leads_Rotated_since_last_clear__c field on the lead rotator user found in comment 4
    //8--Assign the lead to the rep identified in comment 4


    webservice static string rotateLead(list<id> leadsToRotate){
        //declare variables
        string strTerritoryFromLead;
        string strLeadRotatorUser;
        lead leadFromID;
        boolean boolOutsideRepFromLead;
        string strUserName = Userinfo.getFirstName() + ' ' + userinfo.getLastName();
        Lead_Rotator_Users__c LeadRotatorUser;
        list<Rotated_Lead__c> NewRotatedLeads = new list<Rotated_Lead__c>();
        list<lead> LeadsToUpdate = new list<lead>();
        string returnString;
        lead[] leads = [
            select id, Territory__c, F1000_Headquarters_lead__c
            from lead
            where ID in :leadsToRotate
        ];

        //loop through the leads in the list returned by the method
        for (lead l : leads){ 

            //Take ID from page, and assign to a lead variable
            //leadFromID = [select ID,Territory__c,F1000_Headquarters_lead__c from lead where id=:l];

            //assign varables values from the lead
            strTerritoryFromLead = l.Territory__c;
            if(string.isblank(strTerritoryFromLead)){ 

                returnString = 'Error in processing some of the leads, please check the address for State and zip.'; 
                continue;
            }

            boolOutsideRepFromLead = l.F1000_Headquarters_lead__c;

            system.debug('territory variable: '+ strTerritoryFromLead); 
            system.debug('f1000 flag on lead: ' + boolOutsideRepFromLead); 
            system.debug('lead ID: ' + l.id); 
            system.debug('strUserName: ' + strUserName);


            LeadRotatorUser = 
            [  
            //Query to determine next person to rotate to
            SELECT Id,Name,Outside_Rep__c,Territory__c, Leads_Rotated_since_last_clear__c,Rep_Name__c FROM Lead_Rotator_Users__c 
            WHERE Outside_Rep__c = :boolOutsideRepFromLead AND Territory__c = :strTerritoryFromLead 
            ORDER BY Leads_Rotated_since_last_clear__c ASC NULLS FIRST LIMIT 1
            ];

            Rotated_Lead__c rl = new Rotated_Lead__c(
                Lead__c =l.id, 
                Lead_Rotated_by__c = strUserName, 
                Rep_Rotated_To_ID__c = LeadRotatorUser.id
                );//Create lead to insert into the Rotated Lead Table
            system.debug('RL = ' + rl);

            //insert rl;//insert to the rotated lead table
            NewRotatedLeads.add(rl);

            if(Leadrotatoruser.Leads_Rotated_since_last_clear__c == null){
            Leadrotatoruser.Leads_Rotated_since_last_clear__c = 1;  
            }else{
            Leadrotatoruser.Leads_Rotated_since_last_clear__c ++; //increment the counter on the lead rotator user
            }
            update LeadRotatorUser; //update the lead rotator user

            l.ownerID = LeadRotatorUser.Rep_Name__c;
            l.Lead_Rotator_Used__c = true;

            Leadstoupdate.add(l);


        }//end loop through leads in the list returned by the method
        try{
            update leadsToUpdate;
            insert NewRotatedLeads; 
        } catch (dmlException e){
            system.debug('Error: ' + e);

        }

        if (string.isblank(returnString)){
        return 'success';
        }else{
            return returnString;
        }
    }//rotateLead Method end




    webservice static string clearLeadRotatorUsers(list<id> ids){
        list<Lead_Rotator_users__c> usersToUpdate = new list<Lead_Rotator_users__c>();

         Lead_Rotator_users__c[] usersToClear = [
            select id, Leads_Rotated_since_last_clear__c
            from Lead_Rotator_users__c
            where ID in :ids
        ];

        for(Lead_Rotator_users__c u : usersToClear){
        u.Leads_Rotated_since_last_clear__c = 0;
        u.last_clear_date__c = system.now();
        usersToUpdate.add(u);
        }
        try{
            update usersToUpdate;
            return 'success';

        }catch (dmlException e){
            return 'e';
        }



    }

} //End Class
```

And here is my test Class:

```
@isTest
private class LeadRotatorTestClass {

    static testMethod void myUnitTest() {

       lead l = new lead(LastName='Jack Skellington',Email='test@test.com', company='Test Co.', Phone='5555555555', status='Open', Leadsource='Inbound Call', State='OR');
       System.debug('Owner ' + l.Ownerid);

       // Insert lead
       insert l;

       // set to reassign
       l = [SELECT ownerid FROM Lead WHERE Id =:l.Id];


      //lead_rotator__c lr = new lead_rotator__c();
       string result;
       //update lead
       result = leadrotator.rotateLead(l);

       //check 
       System.debug('Owner after trigger fired' + l.ownerid);
       system.debug('Result = ' + result);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing in a lead into the web service, but the method is expecting a type of List Id - so you need to pass that in for the test to work.

So you can just do something like:

```
List<Id> webIds = new List<Id> ();
webIds.add(l.Id);
...
result = leadrotator.rotateLead(webIds);
```