# how to call webservice method from test class

Tags: unit-test

This my web service method in controller:

```
webservice static void generatePoints(Id opportunityRecID) {  
 ...some logic... 
}
```

how to call this method from test class?

please help me

Answer (score 2):

To call this method from your test class. You just need to follow things

```
Test.startTest();
    Classname.generatePoints(Id OpprtunityId) //create opportunity REcord in test class and pass Id here
Test.stopTest();
```

If you are making HTTP callout from this class then you need to use [mock callout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm).

Comment: @cloudZigZag link added.

Answer (score 1):

Test methods don’t support Web service callouts and tests that perform Web service callouts are skipped. To prevent tests from being skipped and to increase code coverage, Apex provides the built-in WebServiceMock interface and the Test.setMock method that you can use to receive fake responses in a test method.

You can get information from below link

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing.htm

Answer (score 0):

Testing method in Apex that is annotated as webservices should not be different from testing any other static method. Please find an example as below.

```
global class DemoApexWebService {
    global class AccountInfo {
        WebService String AccName;
        WebService Integer AccNumber;
    }

    WebService static Account createAccount(AccountInfo info) {
        Account acct = new Account();
        acct.Name = info.AccName;
        acct.AccountNumber = String.valueOf(info.AccNumber);
        insert acct;
        return acct;
    }
}

You can test the above with the following test class:


@isTest
private class TestNewWebService
{
  static testMethod void testNewWebService()
  {
      DemoApexWebService.AccountInfo acc = new DemoApexWebService.AccountInfo();
      acc.AccName = 'ABC';
      acc.AccNumber = 123;
      DemoApexWebService.createAccount( acc );

      Account[] a = [select AccountNumber from Account where AccountNumber = '123'];
      System.assertEquals(a.size(), 1);
  }
}
```

You can find another example here [Having trouble calling a webservice method from apex test class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/31426/having-trouble-calling-a-webservice-method-from-apex-test-class)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create mock class in order to cover webservice test class.